# SQL SERVER apagar registro após UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Gostaria de saber se tem como apagar os registros da tabela origem após realizar o UPDATE em outra tabela, isto é, apagar a linha (da tabela origem) que foi usada no update de outra tabela. Já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei material , ou não sei onde procurar. Valeu!

Comment: Dê um exemplo do que deseja fazer juntamente com a definição das tabelas envolvida. Sua explicação está meio confusa.

Comment: Você provavelmente vai conseguir fazer o que quer usando triggers, mas explique melhor seu cenário para ficar mais clara sua situação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar fazer isso utilizando Triggers. Veja se o laboratório abaixo te ajuda:

1 - Criar Duas Tabelas (Table1 e Table2)

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
    id INT,
    descricao NVARCHAR(40)
  )

  CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (
    id INT,
    descricao NVARCHAR(40)
  )
```

2 - Inserir Registros para Teste:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id,descricao) VALUES (1,'Registro 1 TABELA 1');
INSERT INTO Table1 (id,descricao) VALUES (2,'Registro 2 TABELA 1');

INSERT INTO Table2 (id,descricao) VALUES (1,'Registro 1');
INSERT INTO Table2 (id,descricao) VALUES (2,'Registro 2');
```

3 - Criar um Trigger de UPDATE para a tabela Table2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_TABLE2_AI
ON dbo.Table2
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @ID INT

    SELECT @ID = id FROM INSERTED

    
    DELETE FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE id = @ID
    
END
GO
```

4 - Teste de Atualização:

```
UPDATE  dbo.Table2 
SET dbo.Table2.descricao = t1.descricao
FROM  dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE t1.id = dbo.Table2.id
AND t1.id = 2
```

OBS: Pelos testes que fiz obtive os seguintes resultados:

Antes da atualização:

[image: Antes Atualização]

Depois da Atualização:

[image: Despois da Atualização]

OBS> O artigo abaixo é bem explicativo sobre triggers. Recomendo a leitura:

https://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-no-sql-server-teoria-e-pratica-aplicada-em-uma-situacao-real/28194

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, Gabriel. Muito obrigada!